# Wrong Moscow timezone in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, timezone

For Moscow, the time zone of GMT +3 should be set. But in fact, for Moscow is established GMT +4. As a result, in the whole system of Magento (in orders, email, etc.) I get time for +1 more than now.
How can this be remedied? It looks like a bug.

In the configuration selected Europe/Moscow timezone.

P.S. Time zone GMT +4 operated for Moscow in 2014, then it was transferred to GMT +3.

Magento 2.2.4, CentOS 7.5

Comment: Do you got any solution for this?